# Not able to install gcc and g++

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, gcc, g++

I have `rm-r` all the files starting with `gcc` and `g++` from my `/usr/bin`..

Now when I am trying to reinstall it using `sudo apt-get install gcc` I am getting following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgcrypt20:i386 libsystemd0:i386 linux-headers-4.4.0-38 linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up gcc (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gcc doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package gcc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gcc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends gcc 
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get autoclean -y
sudo apt-get clean gcc
```

These were the results:

```
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation   
or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages   
have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.   
The following information may help to resolve the situation:   
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
 build-essential : Depends: g++ (>= 4:5.2) but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends gcc 
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get autoclean -y
sudo apt-get clean gcc
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply!! I have applied all 3 steps mentioned above...Got new error as below...

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: g++ (>= 4:5.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll make progress faster if you install synaptic. You'll get a nicer view of your situation.

I guess you have some incompatible libraries installed and those are "wedged". g++ or gcc depend on them, but something funny in your versioning prevents apt-get from updating those pieces.  Perhaps they were installed from a third party repository?

Suggestion in @Benny's answer to force remove gcc and g++ might be step in good direction, but since g++ is blocked from installation by some unknown third library, it does not help you to get all the way home.  Depending on how you got in this situation, you may end up removing several layers.

After using `synaptic` to figure out what is going on,  I'd change to terminal and use `dpkg` to remove the packages, not `apt-get`, because I'd avoid any entanglement with internet package servers while stripping things away. You don't generally have to worry about removing things because apt-get will put back the dependencies. However, if you are not careful, then removing one package might trigger the removal of 100s unnecessarily.  Read `man dpkg`, I expect "--no-force-depends" may help. Avoid --force if you can, but "--ignore-depends=?pkg_name" may help. I'd try this in dry-run mode first to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Also could try clicking the *Edit* -> *Fix Broken Packages* option in Synaptic. Sometimes it fixes some of the broken packages the first time that it is clicked and if you click it again it fixes additional broken packages the second time that it is clicked.